# Get substring after a known string up to the first optional comma

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

please help me build regular expression (php)

```
$a = "Вид=Готовый, Литраж=4, Цвет=красный, ";
preg_match('/^.*Вид=(.+),?.*$/', $a, $match);
```

i see manual, it's not work.

i need to get "Готовый" from string, comma may not be
Thank you.

Comment: Use `'~Вид=\K[^,]+~u'`

Comment: Seems to work here, https://3v4l.org/e9WYM although some versions require the `u` modifier. What happens when you run this; how is it not working?

Comment: php version is 5.6.29, code above returns string "Готовый, Литраж=4, Цвет=красный, "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
$a = "Вид=Готовый, Литраж=4, Цвет=красный, ";
if (preg_match('/Вид=\K[^,]+/u', $a, $match)) {
  echo $match[0]; // => Готовый
}
```

See the [online PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/t9d4M)

**Pattern details**

- `Вид=` - a literal string
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the match buffer
- `[^,]+` - 1 or more chars other than a comma